# Opening the same file simultaneously with 'r' and with 'w' removes content

Tags: python, file

Here is my code:

```
def repair():
  option_dict = {'1': 'Save', '2': 'Save_as', '3': 'run'}
  i = 1
  options_read = open('keybinds.options', 'r')
  options_write = open('keybinds.options', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
  for line in options_read.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith(f'{option_dict[str(i)]}:'):
      i += 1
    else:
      print(f'Repairing keybind #{i} ({option_dict[str(i)]})')
      lines = options_read.readlines()
      lines[i-1] = option_dict[str(i)] + ": " + "\n"
      options_write.write(lines)
      i += 1

repair()
```

But when I run it my file changes from

```
Save: <Control-s>
Save_as: <Control-o>
run: <Control-r>
```

to blank.

Also, I know that

```
option_dict[str(i)] + ": " + "\n"
```

will remove

```
<Control-s>
```

I was just testing if

```
lines[i-1] = option_dict[str(i)] + ": " + "\n"
options_write.write(lines)
```

would actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You file becomes blank after `options_write = open('keybinds.options', 'w', encoding='utf-8')`

Try to read it first, then write its content.

You do not open it simultaneously for reading and writing. You open it for writing first and this truncates the file.